# C# WinForms Need to ensure UserControl size

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, resize, custom-controls

I have custom control inherited from UserControl. I need to ensure that it is squared.
So, I need smth like that:

```
int side = Math.Max(this.Width, this.Height);
this.Size = new Size(side, side);
```

But where should I implement this logic? I cannot do it in OnResize because it causes recursive calls and crashes Visual Studio in design mode, or app in runtime.

Comment: onresize should not cause a loop into crashing. some other factor may be causing this

Comment: As @mw509 said, the `OnResize` will not cause that. It should however trigger **once** or **twice** depending on if you resized squared by chance or not.

Answer (score 0):

To keep a squared aspect, I suggest to override **`OnLayout`** instead of **`OnResize`**, the latter can be called more than once when the UserControl is resized in the Form designer or at run-time.
`OnLayout` is called multiple times when the UC is first created (it has to, the size is set multiple time in the initialization).

You also need to check whether the UserControl's Size is scaled down or up:

- If the UC is scaled up, you set the squared size to `Math.Max(Width, Height)`
- If the UC is scaled down, you set the squared size to `Math.Min(Width, Height)`

You have perform this check otherwise, when - for example - the US is scaled up, you won't be able to resize it to a value that is lower that `Max(Width)` or `Max(Height)` (i.e., when scaled up, it won't ever scale down).

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    int m_Squared = 0;

    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Test with and without setting these
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(100, 100);
        this.MinimumSize = new Size(300, 300);
    }

    protected override void OnLayout(LayoutEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLayout(e);

        m_Squared = (this.Width > m_Squared || this.Height > m_Squared) 
                  ? Math.Max(this.Width, this.Height) 
                  : Math.Min(this.Width, this.Height);
        this.Bounds = new Rectangle(this.Location, new Size(m_Squared, m_Squared));
    }
}
```